# Why do these 2 zsh inline commands return different results (Mac OS Sonoma)?

Tags: zsh, macos

So I've been playing around with merging "dot_bar" files in mac OS into their core file. One thing I wanted to do was to find all the "dot_bar" files on my Mac (M1 MacBook Air). the find takes some time, so wanted to bracket the file list output with the date/time.

So after a bit of experimentation I executed -

```
(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M") && sudo -A find / -name "._*" 2>/dev/null &&
  (date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
```

This displays the start date/time and the "dot_bar" files but fails to show the end date/time.

Changing the code to -

```
(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M") && sudo -A find /Volumes -name "._*" 2>/dev/null && 
  (date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
```

Shows the start date/time, files list and end date/time.

So the only difference, I believe, is whether the path for find is "/" or "/Volumes".

Why the different output - i.e. the first option not printing the ending date/time and the second printing the ending date/time?

Thanks,

Very confused :)

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` means "only run the next command if the previous one completed successfully". So this would happen if the `find` command fails, i.e. exits with a non-0 status. This isn't related to whether any files were found, it would happen if `find` couldn't actually search, not if it could search but it found nothing. My guess is that if you try again, but without the `2>/dev/null` you will see that the second command returned an error.

To illustrate:

```
$ find . -name file_that_does_not_exist && echo yes
yes
$ find directory_that_does_not_exist -name whatever && echo yes
find: ‘directory_that_does_not_exist’: No such file or directory
$
```

So, this suggests that the `find /` command is encountering errors. And indeed, Kusalananda pointed out in a comment that `sudo find /` returns various errors about `Operation not permitted`, or `No such file or directory` for stuff under `/Library/Caches` and `/System/Volumes`, `/private/var`, and other places. This means that the command finishes with a non-0 exit code (failure), and so the second `date` command isn't run.

Comment: You've got it backwards. It is the `/Volumes` search that runs fine while the search from the root fails. This is probably due to some directory (outside of `/Volumes`) being inaccessible to the root user. I'm going to check which one it might be in a short while ...

Comment: Yep, the root user should expect to see quite a number of "Operation not permitted", "No such file or directory" errors for stuff under `/Library/Caches` and `/System/Volumes`, `/private/var`, and other places.  The `find` operation eventually finishes, returning a non-zero exit status, causing the end timestamp not to print.

Comment: Thanks, @Kusalananda. Yes, I had the two commands mixed up (fixed now) but the gist of the answer is the same: `find` must be erroring out as you explained.

Comment: So no longer confused... Thanks both, simple and "almost" complete answer :). So guess I should use ';' rather than '&&' to link each command?

Comment: @DownUnder62 yes, if you don't want the execution of the next command to depend on whether the first succeeded, you need `;`.